# Need result of dynamic SQL into a variable

Tags: sql-server

What I want to do is to get the “single value result” of the query in a variable @var. The output of the query is not a recordset but a single string value. The Data should Look Something like this “London,Nottingham,Birmingham,Manchester,Leeds,Blackpool….”

```
Declare @Var nvarchar(MAX)
Declare @DynamicSQL nvarchar(MAX)

BEGIN
    SET @DynamicSQL = 'SELECT   [CityName] from [TempTable]'
    print @DynamicSQL
END

exec sp_executesql @DynamicSQL, N'@Var nvarchar(max) out', @Var out

select @Var
-- Returns String : 'Null'
-- Expected Result: 'London,Nottingham,Birmingham,Manchester,Leeds,Blackpool'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the output variable within the sql statement as follows:

```
SET @DynamicSQL = 'SELECT @Var = [CityName] from [TempTable]'
```

Comment: BeanFrog you rock. Works fine. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to write the return value of `CityName` into the variable `@var` in your dynamic SQL statement.

```
'SELECT   @var = [CityName] from [TempTable]'
```

The result would then be the last row of the `CityName` column, as the variable has been overwritten for the other rows:

[image]

So to concatenate the rows, you need to add the next row result to your variable for each row and add a comma in between. That's how you do it:

```
'SELECT   @var = [CityName] + @var + '','' from [TempTable]'
```

Then in yours output you need to remove all empty spaces in the string:

```
-- remove empty spaces
set @Var = REPLACE(@Var,' ','')

-- remove last comma
set @Var = LEFT(@Var,LEN(@Var)-1)

select @Var
```

The result should then look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. Your query is useful too. thx